# Observability of a system with affine polytopic parametric uncertainty

Tags: control-theory, model-predictive-control

I have the following system with affine parametric uncertainty:
$$x(k+1)=A_{\theta} \ x(k) + B \ u(k)$$
$$y(k)=C_{\theta} \ x(k) + D \ u(k)$$

where $$A_{\theta} = A_0 + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n_p} [\theta]_i A_i $$
$$C_{\theta} = C_0 + \sum\limits_{i=1}^{n_p} [\theta]_i C_i $$
and $\theta \in \Theta$: a convex polytope in $\mathbb{R^{n_p}}$; $A_i,C_i$ are constant matrices.

Is there a way to check the observability condition on $(C,A)$ for all values of $\theta$ in $\Theta$?

Any hints would be appreciated, thanks.

Edit_1:

- $\theta$ is considered to be constant, and it exists inside the known set $\Theta$.
- The observer is to estimate the state variable $x$, not $\theta$.
- I know how to check the observability of a simple LTI system, using the rank of the [observability matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observability), or using [Hautus Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hautus_lemma), but how can we check the rank of a matrix that is a function of $\theta$?
- I was thinking of turning the problem into an optimization problem since $\Theta$ is convex, but I am not sure how can I do that...

Comment: What have you tried? Alternatively, what is the context behind this problem; where did you find it, and what relevant knowledge do you have?

Comment: More context is needed. Are you simply trying to establish the observability/detectability of the pair or are you also trying to construct an observer for the system? Also, is the parameter $\theta$ time-varying? This is important here.

Comment: @C-RAM , In fact, the problem context is a bit complicated, so I tried to isolate the question from the context. 
Context: I am trying to design a Robust Learning-based Model Predictive controller (MPC), which will learn the value of $\theta$, however, some of the state variables are not measurable, so I want to design an observer to estimate these state variables. To guarantee robustness, I have to prove that the system will be observable no matter where the true parameter theta is.
I know the simple observability condition, and Hautus-Lemma, but they are for fixed systems with no params.

Comment: @KBS , for now I will consider $\theta$ to be **constant** and inside a **known** polytopic set $\Theta$.

I actually need both, to check the observability, and to design the observer, but for this question, I am trying to check the observailbity. 

Please note that the observer is for estimating some of the state variables $x$, and NOT the parameter $\theta$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways, some being mathematically easier but more restrictive/conservative. Clearly, it is difficult to ensure that the rank condition holds because of the presence of the parameters.

However, if the pair $(A(\theta),C(\theta))$ is observable or, at least detectable, then there exists a parameter-dependent matrix $L(\theta)$ such that $A(\theta)-L(\theta)C(\theta)$ is Schur stable for all $\theta\in\Theta$. The difficulty here is that $L(\theta)$ is not necessarily affine in $\theta$ (in fact, it does not need to) and it is unclear how it could be computed efficiently.

On top of that, the Schur stability of $A(\theta)-L(\theta)C(\theta)$ for all $\theta\in\Theta$ is only a necessary condition for the stability of the associated parameter-varying system $\dot{x}=(A(\theta)-L(\theta)C(\theta))x$. But if the parameters vary sufficiently slowly, then stability of the system also holds. This may be difficult to quantify.

One way is to overcome that is to consider a constant observer gain and try to show that $$(A(\theta)-LC(\theta))^TP(A(\theta)-LC(\theta))-P$$ is negative definite for some positive definite $P$ and for all $\theta\in\Theta$. This can be exactly reformulated as the following Linear Matrix Inequality (LMI) problem

$$\begin{bmatrix}
-P & (PA(\theta)-UC(\theta))^T\\
PA(\theta)-UC(\theta) & -P
\end{bmatrix}\prec0,$$

where the inequality sign means that the expression is negative definite and the two decision variables are $P\succ0$ and $U$. Again that must hold for all $\theta\in\Theta$.

Assume that $\Theta$ is the unit-simplex (any convex polytope can be transformed to the unit-simplex), then by exploiting the linearity of the conditions in $\theta$, this expression can be rewritten as

$$\begin{bmatrix}
-P & (PA_0-UC_0+PA_i-UC_i)^T\\
PA_0-UC_0+PA_i-UC_i & -P
\end{bmatrix}\prec0,$$

which must now holds for some $P\succ0$, $U$, and all $i=1,\ldots,n_p$. When this holds, the observer gain is given by $L=P^{-1}U$. Both conditions imply that $A(\theta)-LC(\theta)$ is Schur stable for all $\theta\in\Theta$.

This has several drawbacks

1. We use a constant observer gain and so, this restricts the structure of the observer. If $\theta$ is **not known** there is nothing we can really do.
2. We use a constant matrix $P$, which results in a "quadratic stability" result. This could be refined using a parameter-dependent matrix $P(\theta)$ which as the same structure as the system. In that case, a possible condition (assuming constant parameters) is

$$\begin{bmatrix}
-P(\theta)+X(A(\theta)-LC(\theta))+(A(\theta)-LC(\theta))^TX^T & -X+A(A(\theta)-LC(\theta))^TX^T\\
-X^T+X(A(\theta)-LC(\theta)) & P(\theta)-X-X^T
\end{bmatrix}\prec0,$$

where $X$ is a new decision matrix (slack-variable). It can be shown using the elimination lemma, Finsler's lemma or projection lemma, that the above inequality implies that

$$
(A(\theta)-LC(\theta))^TP(\theta)(A(\theta)-LC(\theta))-P(\theta)\prec0,
$$
which implies that $A(\theta)-LC(\theta)$ is Schur stable for all $\theta\in\Theta$.

Assuming now that $P$ is affine in $\theta$ and that $\Theta$ is the unit simplex, we get the equivalent condition

$$\begin{bmatrix}
-P_0-P_i+(X\bar A_i-U\bar C_i)+(X\bar A_i-U\bar C_i)^T & -X+(X\bar A_i-U\bar C_i)^T\\
-X^T+X\bar A_i-U\bar C_i & (P_0+P_i)-X-X^T
\end{bmatrix}\prec0,$$

for some $P_i\succ0,X,U$ and for all $i=1,\ldots,n_p$, where $\bar A_i:=A_0+A_i$, $\bar C_i:=C_0+C_i$. When this holds, the observer gain is given by $L=P^{-1}U$.

---

I am posting already this and will improve it later. I am hungry.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer! I am going to need some time to understand it before accepting it, but thank you in advance!

Comment: If I understand correctly, the logic that you used is that, if $(A(\theta), C(\theta))$ is observable, then there exists $L(\theta), P(\theta)$ that satisfy the LMIs, and then you found a $P(\theta), L(\theta)$ using these LMIs. 

However, does that mean that the opposite direction logic holds? so if $L(\theta)$ exists then the system is observable? is it possible that we find $L(\theta)$, but the observer will converge and stabilize around a wrong value because the system is unobservable?

Comment: About the details, in the second LMI, you checked the inequality on the vertices of the unit-box $\Theta$, Why is it enough to check the vertices, instead of checking on all $\theta \in \Theta$? 
Also, can you recommend a reference for me to understand how you used the slack variables? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Regarding your first post, no, I have not used the observability property, this is rather a quadratic detectability property. Note that the in the first LMI, the matrix $P$ is constant. The feasibility of the LMI implies detectability for all parameters, but not the other way round. Same comment for the second LMI using a parameter dependent $P(\theta)$,

Comment: It is enough to check at the vertices as the condition is affine in the parameters. You can look at the books by Rotondo or Briat if you want to know more about LPV systems. They also consider slack-variables. Those are also discussed in the book by Ebihara et al.